# How to use vuejs as UMD with webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to define vue as external but webpack is handling it like an ESM. I am overriding the vue alias in the webpack config from the default `{ 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' }` to `{ 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js' }` so that I can use the UMD instead of ESM. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Are  you building  libray or app ?

Comment: These are nested projects, and I don't want to keep the common dependencies in both the `node_modules`. I did the same thing with jquery but vue since is used as ESM by default, it doesn't resolve as external the same way.